# Showing the distinct values using key property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm building a category filter and I'm stuck at showing the duplicates of options.

I have an array of objects:

```
filterData = [
  { name: 'Aang', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' },
  { name: 'Appa', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'no', show: 'ATLA' },
  { name: 'Asami', bender: 'no', nation: 'Republic City', person: 'yes', show: 'LOK' },
  { name: 'Azula', bender: 'no', nation: 'Fire', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }
];
```

As you can see, the 'bender' property only has two variants: yes and no. I have tried to get a separate array of yes's and no's:

```
benderArray = this.filterData.map((e) => {
    return e.bender
  })
```

and I'm trying to display each value with an option tag, but I need only unique values.

```
<select id="bender" value={this.state.bender}>
  {benderArray.map(option => <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>)}
</select>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `set`, which will automatically remove all duplicate values for you:

```js
const filterData = [{ name: 'Aang', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Appa', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'no', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Asami', bender: 'no', nation: 'Republic City', person: 'yes', show: 'LOK' }, { name: 'Azula', bender: 'no', nation: 'Fire', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }];

const filtered = [...new Set(filterData.map(i => i.bender))]
console.log(filtered)
```

You can use a `set` with `reduce`, too, and add the values as you go:

```js
const filterData = [{ name: 'Aang', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Appa', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'no', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Asami', bender: 'no', nation: 'Republic City', person: 'yes', show: 'LOK' }, { name: 'Azula', bender: 'no', nation: 'Fire', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }];

const set = new Set([])
const filtered = filterData.reduce((a, {bender:b}) => (!set.has(b) && set.add(b) && a.push(b), a), [])
console.log(filtered)
```

Lastly, you could use `reduce` alone:

```js
const filterData = [{ name: 'Aang', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Appa', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'no', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Asami', bender: 'no', nation: 'Republic City', person: 'yes', show: 'LOK' }, { name: 'Azula', bender: 'no', nation: 'Fire', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }];

const filtered = filterData.reduce((a, {bender:b}) => (!a.includes(b) && a.push(b), a), [])
console.log(filtered)
```

If you wanted to, you could make this a utility function, so you can call it on other properties:

```js
const filterData = [{ name: 'Aang', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Appa', bender: 'yes', nation: 'Air', person: 'no', show: 'ATLA' }, { name: 'Asami', bender: 'no', nation: 'Republic City', person: 'yes', show: 'LOK' }, { name: 'Azula', bender: 'no', nation: 'Fire', person: 'yes', show: 'ATLA' }];

const getUniqueValues = (data, prop) => {
    const s = new Set([])
    return filterData.reduce((a, {[prop]:p}) =>
        (!s.has(p) && s.add(p) && a.push(p), a)
    , [])
}

console.log(getUniqueValues(filterData, 'bender'))
console.log(getUniqueValues(filterData, 'show'))
console.log(getUniqueValues(filterData, 'nation'))
```

From this [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/set-v-reduce), you can see that `set` + `reduce` is the best way to go:
[image: JSPerf]

Answer (score 0):

You should filter your array beforehand to keep only unique values

```
benderArray = this.filterData.map((e) => {
    return e.bender
  }).filter((e, index, self) => self.indexOf(e) === index);
```